# Copying InputStream to OutputStream halts unless I also write to System.out

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

So, I have a Python process I am running from inside Java. I am trying to copy its output to an OutputStream. The process runs correctly; however, whenever I try to copy `Process#getInputStream()` and `Process#getErrorStream()` to an OutputStream, the program hangs.
To debug it, I added in a print statement to output the buffer at every iteration like so:

```
public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int n = 0;
    while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        // I have no clue why, but this only works if I print the output to sysdout
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Doing this, for some bizarre reason, made everything work as intended. Trying to flush the OutputStream, flush System.out, or printing an empty character to stdout, or event printing the plain `byte[] buffer` does not work, only what I have above does.

What is going on with my code that this happens?

**Edit: showing usage**

```
public int runModule(OutputStream moduleOut, int argShowRange, List<String> arguments) throws IOException {

    int status = -1;
    Logger logger = Util.getOutputStreamLogger(moduleOut);
    logger.info("Starting module {}", getModuleName());

    ProcessBuilder exec = new ProcessBuilder();
    exec.directory(getWorkingDirectory());
    if (configureEnvironment(exec.environment(), moduleOut)) {

        List<String> command = getExecutable();
        command.addAll(arguments);
        exec.command(command);

        LOGGER.info("With PYTHONPATH: {}", exec.environment().get("PYTHONPATH"));
        LOGGER.info("In: {}", getWorkingDirectory());
        LOGGER.info("Executing: {}", StringUtils.join(command, " "));
        Process proc = exec.start();
        LOGGER.info("Copying input stream");
        copy(proc.getInputStream(), moduleOut);

        try {
            logger.info("Waiting for process");
            status = proc.waitFor();
            if (status != 0) {
                logger.error("The process failed with the following error: ");
                copy(proc.getErrorStream(), moduleOut);
            }
            logger.info("The process finished with exit code: {}", status);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("The thread was interrupted", e);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("Module configuration failed");
    }
    Util.detachOutputStreamFromLogger(logger);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: This isn't even slightly likely. You fixed something else at the same time. NB It should be `new String(buffer, 0, n)`, or `System.out.write(buffer, 0, n)`. The copy loop will block whenever there is no input. Have you closed the input stream of he process? Are you consuming its standard error stream?

Comment: @EJP I am using this to consume both the standard error stream and standard output stream. After copying from the streams, I then call `Process#waitFor()`, however execution never reaches that point. I will update the question to show how I am using this.

Comment: 1. You haven't closed the process's input stream. 2. You need to either merge the output and error streams or consume them both simultaneously, in separate threads. 3. What is `moduleOut` connected to?

Comment: @EJP It's connected to the output stream of an `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: You;ve only addressed one of three numbered points. You did the same thing last time. I get tired of repeating myself.

Comment: I hadn't done any of the items you had addressed. I am now consuming both streams in separate threads, then closing them once Process#waitFor() returns. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EJP suggested, I split the copying of the streams into separate threads via an executor, then I make sure to close them upon completion of the spawned process:

```
public int runModule(OutputStream moduleOut, int argShowRange, List<String> arguments) throws IOException {

    int status = -1;
    Logger logger = Util.getOutputStreamLogger(moduleOut);
    logger.info("Starting module {}", getModuleName());

    ProcessBuilder exec = new ProcessBuilder();
    exec.directory(getWorkingDirectory());
    if (configureEnvironment(exec.environment(), moduleOut)) {

        List<String> command = getExecutable();
        command.addAll(arguments);
        exec.command(command);

        logger.info("With PYTHONPATH: {}", exec.environment().get("PYTHONPATH"));
        logger.info("In: {}", getWorkingDirectory());
        logger.info("Executing: {}", StringUtils.join(command, " "));
        Process proc = exec.start();

        try (InputStream procOut = proc.getInputStream(); InputStream procErrOut = proc.getErrorStream()) {
            copy(procOut, moduleOut);
            copy(procErrOut, moduleOut);
            LOGGER.debug("Waiting for process to finish");
            status = proc.waitFor();
            LOGGER.debug("Closing streams");
            procOut.close();
            procErrOut.close();
            logger.info("The process finished with exit code: {}", status);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("The thread was interrupted", e);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("Module configuration failed");
    }
    Util.detachOutputStreamFromLogger(logger);

    return status;
}

public void copy(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int n = 0;
            while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Ya done goofed", e);
        }
    });
}
```